# Google Script All Day Calendar Event with Notification On The Day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a script working fine however, I cannot work out how to add a popup reminder for after an all day event as started.... example:
All day even is midnight to midnight, I want a notification at 9am that day.

my script uses event.addPopupReminder but this seems like it only works for before the event.
When I manually look, you have the option to add a reminder "On the day at 9am" but how do I code this? using -900 within the code does not work

[On the day at 9am](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm7W8.png)

(I've snipped the code)

By default, if the cell is blank, it'll add a notification at 9am the day before, which I want to change to 9am on the day

```
   if (C2 == "") {C2 = '900'}
   event.addPopupReminder(C2)
```

On the spreadsheet, I've entered -900 (for 9am on the day) and -1000 (for 10am on the day), neither have worked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide more working code? And why did you try to pass ```-900``` as parameter, is it documented somewhere that's the way to setup "on the day at 9am" ?

Comment: HI Waxim, it's not documented anywhere to pass -900, it was a failed attempt as logically, I thought it might work given 900 returns 9am on the day before. What I cannot find on the forum boards is a time on the day, for all day events.  Checking on Google, the parameter includes a note to say it's minutes before but there is no parameter for on the day despite having an option when manually editing a future all day event. I can only assume it's either a weird workaround or another parameter not listed https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series

Comment: Did my suggestion answer your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are asking doesn't exist, but there is a way to do it anyway. You just have to calcul the minutes between 9am and the start of your event manually.

You haven't put a lot of code, so I wrote something that probably need to be adapted to your case.

What the following function do :

- Get all events of the day and for each :
- Define the minutes between 9am and the start time
- Add a reminder

```
function setReminderTodayEvents() {

  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(9);
  today.setMinutes(0);
  today.setSeconds(0);

  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
                          .getEventsForDay(today);

  for (var x = 0; x < events.length; x++) {
    var date_start = events[x].getStartTime();
    var delta = (date_start - today) / 1000 / 60; //ms to minute
    events[x].addPopupReminder(delta);
  }
}
```

*Suggestion : add a trigger to execute that function every day between 7 and 8*

**References:**

- [getEventsForDay()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar?hl=fr#geteventsfordaydate)
- [getStartTime()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event?hl=fr#getstarttime)
- [addPopupReminder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event?hl=fr#addpopupreminderminutesbefore)